# Estrutura de banco de dados para sistema multi-idiomas

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Já tenho um sistema desenvolvido, usando várias tabelas no banco de dados.
Tenho que começar a migrar o mesmo para o **inglês** e **espanhol**.

A parte de desenvolvimento eu tenho uma ideia já (não total), mas não sei como deixar no banco de dados.

O que estou pensando em fazer:
Uma tabela de `produtos`, por exemplo, tenho os campos `id` e `name`. Estou pensando em alterar o campo `name` para `name_pt` e acrescentar mais dois campos: `name_en` e `name_es`.
Nesse caso vou ficar com a tabela com os seguintes campos: `id`, `name_pt`, `name_en`, `name_es`. Percebo que também irei ter que alterar no sistema para a entrada de dados para ter esses novos campos de input, fora alguns outros pontos.

Gostaria de saber se essa é uma forma correta ou se tem alguma outra melhor de se cuidar disso?

Não sei se interfere em algo, mas o sistema está sendo desenvolvido em PHP com CodeIgniter e MySql.

Answer (score 2):

Para tornar um sistema multi idiomas você vai ter que refatora-lo praticamente todo.
Acrescentar uma coluna a mais por idioma como você pretende não é considerado uma boa prática (é uma gambiarra). O ideal seria você ter uma tabela de "expressões" com (ExpressionId, languageId, Expression) e usar isso em toda parte, nomes de produtos, mensagens para o usário, labels na interface, etc. Além da refatoração tem o trabalho braçal de trocar todas as strings da interface por essas referências e (dependendo do tamanho do sistema contratar um tradutor). Mas o problema não terminou, você vai ter que mudar máscaras de data/hora, trocar a currency, etc.

Comment: quanto a parte de refatoração do sistema eu já pensei sobre e tentei calcular a quantidade de horas com uma gordura (para se ter uma pequena ideia tem 22 models). Agora como ficaria um exemplo dessa tabela de "expressões"? E sim, tem muito trabalho. Valew

Comment: A tabela depende muito do que você quer. digamos que vc tem três linguagens então tem uma coluna para pega o id dessa linguagem. O id da expressão normalmente eu deixo um char(n) n entre 3 e 7, Que dai eu uso um mnemônico como id que facilita. Também legal é fazer um helper para ir buscar a string correta. Dai ficar vc podes usar algo: ExpHelper("ASKDOWNFILE", 3) que seria algo pegue a expressão "Deseja baixar o arquivo: {0}?" em espanhol do banco.

Answer (score 1):

Como eu faria essa implementação:

- Teria uma tabela contendo todas as expressões em todos os idiomas – por exemplo, `messages`.
- Teria uma segunda tabela contendo os idiomas que a aplicação suporte – por exemplo, `languages` (algumas entradas: `pt_BR`, `en_US`, `es_ES`, etc.)
- A primeira tabela conteria uma coluna dizendo o idioma em que aquela mensagem está (por exemplo, `en_US`) e outra coluna referenciando a mensagem original (pode ser o id da mensagem no idioma nativo da aplicação, por exemplo, inglês)

A partir disso, basta elaborar e executar queries para: verificar quantas mensagens faltam para serem traduzidas e seus respectivos idiomas; quais mensagens não têm tradução; quantas frases o sistema possui; etc.

Enfim, o pessoal propôs diversas soluções e essa eu acho que é uma solução bastante mínima, só contendo uma tabela com todas as mensagens e outra contendo os idiomas (em alguns casos, não precisamos nem dessa segunda tabela, se você colocar as devidas verificações de integridade no banco).

Comment: Então, não sei se entendi, mas pelo que disse o sistema vai ter uma tabela só (ou duas) e a parte de relações do sistema? As partes estáticas do sistema eu já tenho uma boa ideia de como resolver, só não sei bem a parte banco, como por exemplo, menus que tenho no sistema estão no banco de dados, categorias de produtos e por ai vai.

Comment: Eu propus uma concepção de duas tabelas, podendo diminuir para apenas uma se você quiser identificar o idioma na própria tabela de mensagens. Para fins de normalização, entretanto, seria interessante ter duas. O que você pode fazer depois é jogar todas as mensagens para um sistema de cache (ex.: Memcached) e buscar a mensagem por uma função do tipo `getMessage('this is a text', 'pt_BR');`. Se a mensagem não for encontrada, você pode pegar o idioma de fallback (por exemplo, `en_US`) ou imprimir direto o texto que foi colocado na função :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso uma tabela chamada `linguagens` onde eu cadastro nome da linguagem e o shortname (ex.: pt-BR) e a pasta onde ela se encontra!

Tenho um arquivo dentro dessa pasta onde contém `váriaveis de linguagem`.

Então eu verifico a linguagem no banco e puxo essas variáveis. Isso para itens estáticos. Para dinâmicos, no caso, o que vem do banco, eu crio um campo `enum`, que é onde informo a linguagem do texto (pode ser uma notícia, um artigo ou qualquer coisa).

É possível salvar moeda, timezone, tudo nessa tabela de linguagens. Depois você recupera de acordo com a seleção, via cookie do usuário. Se não haver nenhum cookie setado, você informa ao navegador a `linguagem default`.

Answer (score -1):

Use uma tabela separada, uma linha por par (ID de produto, ID de Idioma). facilita muito adicionar um idioma a mais,no futuro. sugiro um padrão como Iso 639 para identificar os idiomas.

Comment: quanto a essa tabela, não sei, mas pode ser algo que o @jean comentou a de "expressões" ou não? E nessa tabela, pensando, então pode ter algo como a string que identifica no final ok.

Comment: Você pode separar também, deixando uma tabela de relacionamento nomesprodutos_idiomas para ser usada no caso especifico dos produtos e uma outra tabela para ser usada pelas expressões do sistema (mensagens, labels, botões, etc)

Comment: Então @jean pelo que entendi essas partes estáticas do sistema (mensagens, labels, botões, etc) eu já tenho uma boa ideia de como fazer, o que não tenho muita ideia é a parte do banco, de como deixar as tabelas, colunas, por causa que tenho menus, produtos, categoria de produtos, artigos entre muitos outros itens que podem ser traduzidos, e essas partes que ainda não entendi bem como deixar.

Comment: Para os dados, com certexa, você pode criar uma tabela de nomes como eu já havia explicado. É mais prático do que criar n colunas/tabela. Você pode usar a mesma tabela para as duas coisas, mas eu pessoalmente prefiro separar oquê é dados do que é resources.